# How do i enable Debug level log in POD

Tags: logging, openshift

I need to enable debug level logs in my Red Hat open shift POD, which is currently having the info level logs. My application version - v3.11.

Comment: There are various ways to enable debug level in Pods and it depends on a Pod. Which Pod and application you want to debug?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Application is a Java based and i have my tomcat POD.

Answer (score 0):

For application pods, the log level can be changed to debug, just as for applications in VMs, like using environment variable, configuring config file or command line arguments.

**Environment variable**

1. `oc set env <object-selection> KEY_1=VAL_1 ... KEY_N=VAL_N` is a way to set environement variable to your deploymentconfig. *1
2. You can use ConfigMap/Secret to specify environment variables as follows *2, *3

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env: 
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config 
              key: special.how 
        - name: TEST_SECRET_USERNAME_ENV_VAR
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: test-secret
              key: username
      envFrom: 
        - configMapRef:
            name: env-config
```

**Config files**

You can mount configmap/secret. *3, *4

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: secret-test-container
      image: busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "cat /etc/secret-volume/*" ]
      volumeMounts:
          # name must match the volume name below
          - name: secret-volume
            mountPath: /etc/secret-volume
            readOnly: true
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: secret-volume
      secret:
        secretName: test-secret
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: special-config
```

**Commandline argument**

You can specify configmap as command line arguments. *5
This is similar to how environment variables are read.

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo $(SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY) $(SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY)" ]
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: special.how
        - name: SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: special.type
```

*1: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/environment_variables.html#set-environment-variables

*2: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-env-vars

*3: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-consuming-in-volumes

*4: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html#secrets-examples

*5: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html#configmaps-use-case-setting-command-line-arguments